# How to interface with the server to upload files (pictures) from my app

Tags: ios, objective-c, file-upload, afnetworking

So I am trying to upload a file (picture) to the a server using their web service called `UploadFile` which takes 2 variables.

`FileInfo info` and a `int requestId` (which in my case will always be 0)
The `FileInfo` object contains several variables `name` (String), `description`(String), `content`(binary data of the file, in this case it would be the image), `id` (String), and `name` (String)

How do I interface with this server to make the request go through? Normally when I have been pulling/posting information I have just been doing JSON calls, but I am guessing uploading is different. I am not sure how to do this when the service requires a custom object to be passed.

Do I need to create the object in my App?

I am trying to use AFNetworking's `AFHTTPRequestOperations` for this.

I am trying to use their example as a springboard, but I still need to make sure on what to change in their upload example since the example uses direct uploading of an image and I need to upload a FileInfo object instead of a jpeg.

```
               NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://SomeDomain.com/Services/FileService.svc/UploadFile"];
                AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];
                NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([self.photoImageView image], 0.5);

                NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"/upload" parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock: ^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData) {

                    [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"avatar" fileName:@"Upload.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpg"];

                }];

                NSLog(@"Request %@", [request description]);

                AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
                NSLog(@"Operation: %@", [operation description]);
                [operation setUploadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesWritten, long long totalBytesWritten, long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {
                    NSLog(@"Sent %lld of %lld bytes", totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite);
                }];
                [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                    NSLog(@"RESPONSE: %@", [responseObject description]);
                } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                    NSLog(@"Failed: %@", [error description]);
                }];
                [httpClient enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operation];
```

Thanks,
Alan

Answer (score 0):

if you see the AFNetworking documentation of the methode multipartFormRequestWithMethod...you have a Dictionnary parameter where you can putt all the infos needed by the Web service.

> /**  Creates an `NSMutableURLRequest` object with the specified HTTP
>   method and path, and constructs a `multipart/form-data` HTTP body,
>   using the specified parameters and multipart form data block. See
>   http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2
>
> Multipart form requests are automatically streamed, reading files
>   directly from disk along with in-memory data in a single HTTP body.
>   The resulting `NSMutableURLRequest` object has an `HTTPBodyStream`
>   property, so refrain from setting `HTTPBodyStream` or `HTTPBody` on
>   this request object, as it will clear out the multipart form body
>   stream.    @param method The HTTP method for the request. This
>   parameter must not be `GET` or `HEAD`, or `nil`.  @param path The path
>   to be appended to the HTTP client's base URL and used as the request
>   URL.  @param parameters The parameters to be encoded and set in the
>   request HTTP body.  @param block A block that takes a single argument
>   and appends data to the HTTP body. The block argument is an object
>   adopting the `AFMultipartFormData` protocol. This can be used to
>   upload files, encode HTTP body as JSON or XML, or specify multiple
>   values for the same parameter, as one might for array values.
>
> @return An `NSMutableURLRequest` object  */

Comment: so in my case, do I put a dictionary containing FileInfo and NSNumber as the parameter? Do I need the use the `[formData appendPartWIthFileData:...]'call in the example?

Comment: any ideas :)? I've been banging my head over this.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this. They have given different methods:
https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking